# Aligning two equations with a 'multiline' bracket around them to previous equations

Tags: latex, amsmath

I am trying to align a set of solutions of an equation to previous equations at the position of their equal signs. Next to the set equations is a bracket that goes over both lines. The code I already have is equivalent to the following:

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align*}
    x^2 & = 1 \\
    \Rightarrow \quad \left\{
    \begin{array}{r l}
        x & = - 1 \\
        x & = 1
    \end{array}
    \right. \\
    x & = 1
\end{align*}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQF6I.png)
Is there or can I set another marker to use for alignment? Are there other equation environments or solutions for the bracket itself that would make this obsolete?
Additionally, is there an option to reduce the space left to the equal signs of the last two equations to 'normal' size (to comparison I copied the last solution inside the normal equation environment)?
Edit: The last problem can be fixed by using `aligned` instead of `array`.
Edit 2: Answer provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637607/aligning-two-equations-with-a-multiline-bracket-around-them-to-previous-equati)!

Comment: Just FYI: There is also a TeX community which exclusively focuses on TeX questions. See [TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).